# Any open source passive monitoring tool like ClientVantage

Tags: performance-monitoring, response-time

I'd like to find an open source tool that do passive performance monitoring. It should:

1. capture network packages between client and server or between servers where the packages comes from a mirrored port in switch
2. recognize the start and end of a user defined transaction, for example the http request and http response packages
3. record the time of request and response packages, and report the average transaction response times
4. runs in production systems

[Compuwares](http://www.compuware.com) [ClientVantage tool](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/33967) seems have these functions,but it is expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PasMon](http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage) seems a similar tool. I encounter the answer in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120022/539582). But PasMon seems not actively developed now